How To Extrude On Curved Surface
how can i extrude shapes on curved surfaces with good shading ?

here's the blend :


Difficult to tell without seeing your Blend file. Have you checked the face orientation after you extruded it? (Check Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays menu.) If that's not it we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

okay i added the blend, btw auto smooth doesn't produce the shading problem but i want the edges beveled and not sharp.
bevelling them manually or with the modif both didn't work.
thank you for the reply

Both Shade Smooth and Shade Smooth by Angle work fine. The Bevel modifier isn't working correctly because you haven't applied the scale to your object. (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode).

shade smooth by angle work fine but i want the edges to be bevelled and it sharpens them.
bevel modifier still has the shading problem in the face supporting the extrusion, applying scale certainly changes how the bevel behaves but is irrelevant to the shading problem.
is there a way to fix shading, and have everything bevelled ?

I don't know how you created that section but it certainly seems to have upset the shading somehow. Clearing Custom Split Normals helps slightly but there is still an issue there for some reason.
